# Закрывается telnet соединение

Tags: c, bash, telnet

Написал простецкий сервер на C, работающий на локалхосте и порте 30000, при наборе такой команды:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 30000
```

Он начинает общаться с юзером, однако я пишу что-то на сервер, он отсылает ответ, и закрывает коннект. Снова приходится логиниться. Как это исправить?
Файл Server.c:

```
#include "../includes/Main.h"

void handle_shutdown(int sig){
if(sock)
    close(sock);
fclose(lg);
fclose(usr);
printf("\nInterrupt has been expected!\n");
exit(0);
}

void login(int sock){

char buffer[20];

say(sock, "Enter your login: ");
read_in(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

char temp[20];
int trash;
while(fscanf(usr, "%s%i", temp, trash) != EOF){
    if(!strcmp(temp, buffer)){
        say(sock, "User with the same login doesn't exist!\n");
        char result[100];
        sprintf(result, "Tried to connect with login %s.", buffer);
        log(result);
        return;
    }
}

char result[50];
sprintf(result, "./users/%s.txt", buffer);
FILE *cUser = fopen(result, "r");
char pass[20];
fscanf(cUser, "%s", pass);
say(sock, "Enter your password: ");
char p[20];
read_in(sock, p, sizeof(p));
if(!strcmp(pass, p)){
    char result[100];
    sprintf(result, "User with login %s is now online.", buffer);
    log(result);
    say(sock, "Successful!");
}else{
    char result[100];
    sprintf(result, "Tryed to login with invalide password as %s.", buffer);
    log(result);
    say(sock, "Invalide password!\n");
}

}

void reg(int sock){
char buffer[20];

say(sock, "Enter your login: ");
read_in(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
char temp[20];
int trash;
while(fscanf(usr, "%s%i", temp, trash) != EOF){
    say(sock, temp);
    if(!strstr(temp, buffer) || buffer[0] == '\0'){
        say(sock, "User with the same login has been already registered!\n");
        return;
    }
}

say(sock, "Enter your password: ");
char pass[30];
read_in(sock, pass, sizeof(pass));

fprintf(usr, "%s1", buffer);

char url[50];
sprintf(url, "./users/%s.txt", buffer);

FILE *user = fopen(url, "w");
fprintf(user, "%s", pass);
fclose(user);
char result[100];
sprintf(result, "User with name %s has been registered.", buffer);
log(result);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
catchSig(SIGINT, handle_shutdown);

lg = fopen("Log.txt", "w");
usr = fopen("./users/Exists.txt", "a+");

sock = create_socket();

bind_to_port(sock, 30000);

listen(sock, 10);

puts("Waiting for connection.");

while(1){
    struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    unsigned int address_size = sizeof(client_addr);
    int connect_d = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &address_size);

    say(connect_d, "Choose operation: \r\n");

    char buffer[255];
    int c = read_in(connect_d, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if(buffer[0] == '\0'){
        say(connect_d, "You sent nothing!");
    }else if(c == -1)
        error("Can't read data!");
    else{
        if(strstr(buffer, "login")){
            login(connect_d);
        }else if(strstr(buffer, "register")){
            reg(connect_d);
        }
    }
    close(connect_d);
}
fclose(lg);
fclose(usr);
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Для начала, показать код. А если хотите играть в угадайку - наверное вы после получения ответа от пользователя завершаете программу, а надо это делать в бесконечном цикле.

Comment: Не закрывать соединения :)

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Запускайте как сервис `inet.d`, например.

Comment: @arrowd Вот, добавил код main'a, как видите тут все в while(1)

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо, вопрос решен так:

После вызова метода accept, создал отдельный дочерний процесс через fork, который в while(1) крутит запросы, а родительский опять ждет accept.